# Unity 2D polygon collider

Tags: unity-game-engine

Is there a way to create 2D polygon collider to work as as perimeter collider?

I want to be inside the polygon and do a raycast to the border. I want the hitpoint to be on the border, not on the location where I am.

Can I use 2D polygon collider for that or do I need to use some other collider?

Comment: raycast is not able to detect the transition from inside a collider to the outside - only outside to the inside. you might be able to put something together with OnCollisionStay however.

Comment: @ryeMoss i read something bout 2DEdgeCollider. What if i construct my polygon out of these edgecolliders. Would that work? Or will it get too slow once my polygon wil have alot of sides?

Comment: I can't see a reason why it wouldn't work. Not sure how it would perform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a polygon shape with 2D Edge Colliders. Just calculate the different spots with the polygon's angles.

I noticed there was an answer saying this already. My bad. :)